# Count number of unique weekdays in a range

Tags: google-spreadsheets

I have a range of dates and I want to count the number times each weekday shows up. Multiple entries on the same date should count as 1.

For example with this data:

```
9/29/2017
9/29/2017
9/30/2017
10/1/2017
10/2/2017
10/2/2017
10/3/2017
10/3/2017
10/3/2017
10/6/2017
10/6/2017
10/6/2017
```

This should return 2 Fridays (Sep 29, Oct 6), and 1 Tuesday (Oct 3).

Answer (score 0):

Get the day of the week in `B2`:

`=TEXT(A2, "DDDD")`

Then `COUNTA()` the unique values in `E2`:

`=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B13,C2:C13=1)))`

[image]